# passing values to constructor. C++

Tags: c++

normally this is how you pass a variable to a constructor from other class.

SampleA.cpp

```
#include SampleA.h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

SampleA::SampleA(string text) 
{
    setText(text);
}    

string SampleA::getText() {
    return text; 
}

void SampleA::setText(string text) {
    this->text = text;
}

void SampleA::displayText() {
    string displayText;
    displayText = getText();
    cout << displayText << endl;
}
```

SampleA.h

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef _testing_ SampleA_h
#define _testing_ SampleA_h

class SampleA     {

private:
    std::string text;
public :    
    SampleA() 
    {
        text = ""; 
    };//default constructor

    SampleA(std::string);
    std::string getText();
    void setText(std::string text);   
};
```

main.cpp

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include SampleA.h
  using namespace std;
  SampleA outputTextValue;

  int main ()  {
     string input;
     cout << "Enter a text" << endl;
     cin >> input;
     //pass the value using SampleA class consturctor
     SampleA storeText(input);
     //output the text from displayText() method from SampleA class
     outputTextValue.displayText(); 
  }
```

I was wondering if you can do the same thing for 2d array.

or rather if you want to pass a 2d array values to a consturctor from other class, what approach should I be using? 
(*the codes shown below  is wrong as it's just a rough example )

SampleA.cpp

```
#include SampleA.h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

SampleA::SampleA(int 2Darray[][2]) 
{
    setText(2Darray[][2]);
}    

string SampleA::get2DArray() {
    return 2Darray[][2]; 
}

void SampleA::set2DArray(string int 2Darray[][2]) {
    this->2Darray[][2] = 2Darray[][2];
}


 void SampleA::displayNumber() {
    cout << get2DArray(); << endl;
}
```

SampleA.h

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef _testing_ SampleA_h
#define _testing_ SampleA_h

class SampleA     {

private:
    int 2Darray[][2];
public :    
    SampleA() 
    {
        2Darray[][2]; 
    };//default constructor

    SampleA(2Darray[][2]);
    std::string get2DArray();
    void set2DArray(2Darray[][2]);   
};
```

main.cpp

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include SampleA.h
  using namespace std;

  SampleA outputMethod;
  int main ()  {
     int storeValue [2][2];
     for(int i =0; i<2; i++) {
        cout << "Enter first number" << endl;
        cin >> storeValue[i][0];
        cout << "Enter first number" << endl;
        cin >> storeValue[i][1];
   }

     //pass the 2dArray value using SampleA class consturctor
     SampleA storeText(storeValue);
     // output method displayNumber() method from SampleA class
     outputMethod.displayNumber();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but not as a proper matrix as arrays decays to pointers when passed as arguments.

You have to do e.g.

```
class SampleA
{
    int (*some2darray)[2];  // `some2darray` is a pointer to an array of two integers
    size_t size;            // Size of "outer" array

public:
    SampleA(int (*arg)[2], size_t sz)
        : some2darray(arg), size(sz)
    {}

    void displayText() const
    {
        std::cout << "Values = { ";

        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            std::cout << "{ " << some2darray[i][0] << ", " some2darray[i][1] << " } ";

        std::cout << "}\n";
    }
};
```

Then do e.g.

```
int storeValue[2][2];
...
SampleA store(storeValue, 2);
store.displayText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing 2D Array:

```
method(array_name);
```

No Brackets no size indicator.

```
setText(2Darray);
```